# Oracle TRUNC date by quarter but with custom year start date

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I need to get aggregate values on a quarterly basis which can be done using the trunc function with the option 'Q' like so

```
select count(*), trunc(DATE_COL, 'Q') from TABLE_NAME
group by trunc(DATE_COL, 'Q')
```

But the problem here is that I need the year to start on the 1st Dec of the previous year instead of 1st Jan (Ex: the Q1 2015 starts on 1-Dec-2014 and ends on 28-Feb-2015, as opposed to 1-Jan-2015 to 31-Mar-2015).
Added: So Q1 includes Dec, Jan, Feb; Q2 includes Mar, Apr, May; Q3 includes Jun, Jul, Aug; Q4 includes Sep, Oct, Nov

PS: I'm using Oracle 11g and I'll be running these queries via PHP 5.3.

Comment: So, you need to use `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END` or write custom function.

Comment: Do you mean that date range?  31-Dec-2014 to 28-Feb-2015 is two months and one day, way short of a Quarter.  What are the values for Q2, Q3, Q4?

Comment: @APC, my bad, I meant 1-Dec and  not 31-Dec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you have several issues here.

1) To push a date from December into the native Q1 bundle, use add_months(:date,1). That moves everything by your offsets into Oracle's Q1,2,3,4 for easy aggregation.

2) Labeling. If you need the query to do dynamic labeling, then APC and Lalit have you covered for finding the correct start date. From there, last_day(add_months(Quarter_start_date,3)) would get you the other endpoint!

3) OK, so are you looking for a return of one row per quarter? Or one row per year with the four quarters as columns? If one row per quarter do you need to ensure that you return a row for a quarter where no data exists?

But to do a simple aggregate by Quarter with your one-month offset:

```
SELECT count(*)
     , add_months(trunc(add_months(your_date_field,1),'Q'),-1) q_start_date
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY  add_months(trunc(add_months(your_date_field,1),'Q'),-1);
```

Comment: I don't think I'll need #3. But thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

> "I need the year to start on the 1st Dec of the previous year instead of 1st Jan (Ex: the Q1 2015 starts on 1-Dec-2014 and ends on 28-Feb-2015"

Okay, so you want to shift all the Quarters back a month.  That's simple: use ADD_MONTHS() with a negative number to subtract a month....

```
select count(*), add_months(trunc(DATE_COL, 'Q'), -1) Q
from TABLE_NAME
group by add_months(trunc(DATE_COL, 'Q'), -1)
```

ADD_MONTHS() is a standard Oracle function.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions011.htm#SQLRF00603).

Comment: I think this will just shift the date in the result, not actually aggregate the values for the required time period.

Comment: Why not? You are aggregating based on the same condition.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, this answer is wrong or at least not what i was looking for. It just aggregates the data in the default way i.e Q1->Jan to Mar, Q2-> Apr to Jun and so on(as opposed to Q1-Dec to Feb, Q2->Mar to May and so on), and shifts the date in the result by a month. Refer Michael Broughton's answer which achieves what i was looking for.

Comment: Ok. Other answers were close.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the year to start on the 1st Dec of the previous year instead of 1st Jan (Ex: the Q1 2015 starts on 1-Dec-2014

To get 1-DEC-2014 instead of 1-JAN-2015 for current quarter, you could shift a day back from this quarter and then get the 1st day of that month.

**Update** [@APC's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28980854/3989608) using **ADD_MONTHS** is nicer and neat than mine using **TRUNC** twice. I advice to use his solution. Mine could be an alternative, just good to know.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT trunc(trunc(SYSDATE, 'Q') - 1, 'month') Q1 FROM dual;

Q1
---------
01-DEC-14

SQL>
```

Try,

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
  TRUNC(TRUNC(DATE_COL, 'Q') - 1, 'month') Q1
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY TRUNC(TRUNC(DATE_COL, 'Q') - 1, 'month');
```

Comment: ADD_MONTHS() is easier to understand.

Comment: @APC, I agree. Looks neat. I got that thought, however, you already posted your answer.